# How to create a pyramid of X's in python

Tags: python

```
   X
  XXX
 XXXXX
XXXXXXX
```

This is one part of the introductory assignment in my computer science course.  The teacher has taught us ranges with regards to i and j.  I have absolutely no idea how to achieve the pyramid, and I've been trying different things for hours.  Aside from the two 50 minute classes I've had, i have never been exposed to any sort of programming.  I would greatly appreciate some help / advice.

this code is the extent of our current instruction and supposed knowledge:

```
for i in range(10):

    line = ""
    for j in range(10):
        if j%2 == 0:
            c = ' '
        else:
            c = '*'
        line += c
    print line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string formatting:

Based on size of the base:

```
def create_pyramid(base):
    for i in xrange(1, base+1, 2):
        print '{:^{}}'.format('X'*i, base)
...         
>>> create_pyramid(7)
   X   
  XXX  
 XXXXX 
XXXXXXX
```

Based on the number of levels:

```
def create_pyramid(level):
    for i in xrange(1, 2*level, 2):
        print '{:^{}}'.format('X'*i, (2*level)-1)
...         
>>> create_pyramid(5)
    X    
   XXX   
  XXXXX  
 XXXXXXX 
XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: +1 for learning how to center with `format`. I would have gone with `print ("X" * i).center(base)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your teacher requires `i` and `j`, I guess he wants some old-school-C-like code, try this:

```
N,line,c,p = 10,'','',1
spaces = ' '*N

for i in range(N):
  spaces = spaces[0:N-i]
  c = ''
  for j in range(p):
    c += "X"
  line += spaces+c+'\n'
  p += 2

print line
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
def create_pyramid(base):

    star = 1 # first row has 1 star
    for i in range((base - 1) / 2, -1, -1): # (base - 1) / 2 will determine the first space given the base
        print i * " ", star * "X" # spaces
        # the , star * "X" on the above line means printing on the same line with no space
        star += 2 # incrementing by 2 each time
...
>>>create_pyramid(7)
   X   
  XXX  
 XXXXX 
XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

Just want to throw another thought.

If you think about modeling the problem in ***functional*** way, you can easily end up with this recursive solution:

```
def pyramid(N, i = 0): 
    if N > 0: 
        print (N - 1) * ' ' + '*' * (i * 2 + 1) 
        pyramid(N - 1, i + 1)

>>>pyramid(5)

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of the problem in terms of not one variable but two. A variable `num_bricks` is the number of 'bricks' in the current level of the pyramid, and a variable `num_spaces` is the number of spaces in the current level.

There should always be as many spaces on one side of the pyramid as there are on the other. So for each line of the pyramid, all you need do is to print half of your spaces, print all of your X's, then print the other half of your spaces (make sure to use `print 'X',` instead of `print 'X'` — the comma at the end means 'don't start a new line'. `print` by itself is good for starting a new line)

for each line:

```
for i in range(num_spaces / 2):
    print ' ',
for i in range(num_bricks):
    print 'X',
for i in range(num_spaces / 2):
    print ' ',

print
#a blank print statement will start a new line without printing anything on it
```

So all that's left to do is find a rule that governs how `num_spaces` and `num_bricks` should increase/decrease from level to level.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pyramid object:

```
class Pyramid(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size=2*size
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join('{:^{}}'.format('*'*i, (self.size)-1) for i in range(1,self.size,2))
```

Then print an instance of it:

```
>>> print Pyramid(7)  
      *      
     ***     
    *****    
   *******   
  *********  
 *********** 
*************
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 for i in range(1,10):
   print (" "*(10-i)+"X"*i+"X"*(i-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the simplest  ways.

```
a = 10
for x in xrange(0,a):
    print (a-x)*" "+x*"x"
```

It counts to 10, and for each row it subtracts the number of `X's` that will be in the row from 10  and will print that many spaces in front of the `X's`, this gives it the pyramid look.

Answer (score 0):

Fun question. Being `n` the height of the pyramid:

```
print('\n'.join(' ' * (n - x - 1) + 'x' * (2 * x + 1) for x in range(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pyramid():
n=int(raw_input("enter a num:"))
for i in range(n):
    print " "*(n-i-1)+"*"*(2*i+1)
pyramid()
```

This is the simplest code i could find ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
num = int(input("Enter a range here:  "))
for i in range(num):
    if i<= num
       print(" "*(num-1-i)+"X "*(i+1))
```